# bitcond v0.12.1. "UpdateTip: 6 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version"

Tags: bitcoind

I replaced my bitcoind from v0.11.2 to v0.12.1. Then I found "UpdateTip: 6 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version" in debug.log. This error occurs at new block generation. Can I ignore this? If not, how can I fix it?

I downloaded the new bitcond from

https://github.com/btcdrak/bitcoin/releases
https://github.com/btcdrak/bitcoin/releases/download/v0.12.1-addrindex/bitcoin-0.12.1-addrindex-linux64.tar.gz

Comment: I'm still getting this on bitcoin core 0.17.1 --- and YES you can just ignore it. "warning='28 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version'"

Comment: I'm seeing "warning='39 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version'". Is that still OK?

At what point it's not ok?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Yes. You can ignore this.**

This means that some miners have mined (still compatible) blocks with a version number unknown to Bitcoin Core.

Generally this indicates that some miners have mined blocks that signal non Bitcoin Core compatible soft- or hard-forks. Very likely a 2MB hardfork after BIP109 implemented by Bitcoin Classic.

Comment: beside ignoring it, can we do something to remove it? ..or i bet it will go away as more block are added to the chain? Got 1 of last 100 about 2 years later than your answer.. and still relevant

Comment: "BIP109 implemented by Bitcoin Classic"

What's "Bitcoin Classic"?