# How to resolve Bitcoin Daemon Warning of last 100 blocks have unexpected version message?

Tags: bitcoind, linux, ubuntu, server, daemon

When I run my bitcoin daemon on ubuntu I get the follow warning message. How do I resolve this? And I just pruned my blockchain to 5gb if that affects anything.

> progress=1.000000 cache=40.4MiB(273342txo) warning='52 of last 100
>   blocks have unexpected version'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bitcond v0.12.1. "UpdateTip: 6 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46318/bitcond-v0-12-1-updatetip-6-of-last-100-blocks-have-unexpected-version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to resolve anything - some miners create arbitrary versions to attempt to speed up the mining process, as it gives them an additional field in the block block header to alter without having to recalculate the merkle root and other fields.

This is harmless, provided they aren't producing invalid blocks for version 2, in which case the block would be rejected

Comment: ok i guess i'll ignore it. how do i even check if the daemon is syncing properly? is there som etype of 100% sync status message?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ if your debug.log file reports `progress=1.0000`, then your node has synced up to the longest chain that it is aware of. You can also run the command `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo` to see more details related to your node's view of the chain.

Comment: i can't just see it somewhere when the bitcoin daemon runs?